# Follow content status while scrolling (JavaScript ?)

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm looking for the library which permit to "follow" what we are reading (related to our scroll) in the content page on the right of it, I saw really similar things on several websites, and I think there is a specific open source library in link with that.

Several websites : [example 1](https://community.grafana.com/t/new-panel-plugin-carpet-plot/1334/14), [example 2](https://tech.korben.info/t/typio-form-recovery-recuperer-le-contenu-d-un-formulaire-web-apres-un-plantage-de-chrome/11577/7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this help. It looks like what you need:

1. http://www.bestjquery.com/demo/jquery-timeline-plugin/
2. https://codepen.io/plasm/pen/oZbXmj

```
$(function(){
  function sumSection(){
    return $(".container").height()
  }
  function setDimensionBar(){
    $(".bar").css({
      "height": ($(window).height()/sumSection())*100 + "%"
    })
  }
  function setSection(){
        $.each($("section"), function(i, element){
      $(element).css({
        "min-height": $(window).height()
      })
      })
  }

  function addBehaviours(){
    let sections = $("section")
    $.each($(".node"), function(i, element){
      $(element).on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        let scroll = $(sections[i]).offset().top
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scroll
        }, 500);
      })
    })
  }

  function arrangeNodes(){
    $(".node").remove()
    $.each($("section"), function(i, element){
      let name = $(element).data("name")
      let node = $("<li class='node'><span>"+name+"</span></li>")
      $(".timeline").append(node)

      $(node).css({
        "top": ($(".timeline").height()/$(document).height()) * $(element).offset().top
      })
    })
    addBehaviours()
  }

  $(window).on("scroll", function(){
    let top = (window.scrollY/sumSection())*100
    $(".bar").css({
        "top": top + "%"
      })

  })

  $(window).on("resize", function(){
    setSection()
    arrangeNodes()
    setDimensionBar()
  })

  setTimeout(
    function(){
      setSection()
      arrangeNodes()
      setDimensionBar()      
    },
    200
  )
})
```

Comment: Yes the second solution looks like what I'm looking for. Thank you !

Comment: @Azrix You can mark my answer as the best - it may be useful for others in the future